# How to keep format of mysql data when exporting to excel file via php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

I am exporting MySql data to excel file using a very simple php code, but I am facing a very annoying problem in the excel data. I am Ok with all data except one column which is stored in MySQL as varchar and contains accounts no. of users and it is normally starts with leading zeros like 0000111122356, 0002345679855, 025478961694 and so on. when I export the same data to excel, it remove the leading zeros and I got 111122356, 2345679855, 25478961694 and so on, which is not acceptable to me.
My php code for export excel file -

```
include('db_connect.php');

$export = mysql_query('Select name, address, bank, bank_account from users') ;

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

//with database field names
for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ ) {
$header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) ) {
$line = '';
//for each field in the row
foreach( $row as $value ) {
    //if null, create blank field
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ){
        $value = "\t";
    }
    //else, assign field value to our data
    else {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    //add this field value to our row
    $line .=  $value;
}
//trim whitespace from each row
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
//remove all carriage returns from the data
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

$file_name = 'excel_data' ;
//create a file and send to browser for user to download
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$file_name.".xls");
print "$header\n$data";
```

MySQL Table format -

```
id(int) name(varchar) address(varchar) bank bank_account(varchar)
1       abd           delhi            0000111122356  
2       xyz           delhi            0002345679855
3       pqr           delhi            025478961694
```

Can anyone please suggest me some changes and trick in my code to handle this situation. I need to export the same data which stored in mysql without and change.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a library to create Excel files like [PHP Excel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), and format the cells of the document to text before putting any values in them, if they are formatted as numbers then the excel will take out the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Try and put an apostrophe (`'`) in front of the cells with leading zeros before exporting to excel. This way Excel should interpret it as text.
havent tried it myself, but it is worth to try I think